# Equivalent of select i.*

Tags: r, join, data.table

I am looking to tidy up some of my data.table codes I have converted from SQL.

table x

```
x <- data.table(a = 1
                ,b = 2); x
#    a b
# 1: 1 2
```

table y

```
y <- data.table(a = 1
                ,c = 3); y
#    a c
# 1: 1 3
```

by default the following join returns ALL columns

```
x[y, on=.(a)]
#    a b c
# 1: 1 2 3
```

where column a takes on value of table i but name from x given format `x[i]`.

My question is whether it is possible to only select ALL columns from table i. This would be `select i.* from...` in SQL. This is invaluable to me as in reality my table i and x both contain a good number of columns and I would like to nest straight into `data.table`'s join clause without listing all table i's columns in `.()` or doing a column selection in a separate line.

Thank you.

Comment: r u looking for `x[y, on=.(a), mget(paste0("i.", names(y)))]`

Comment: Yes. I see we would have to use base R and nest in. There is not a data.table syntax?
Just found out how to manually select columns from x also
x[y, on=.(a), mget(c(paste0("i.", names(y)), "x.a"))]
Thank you @chinsoon12

Comment: pls see "2g) Why keep j so flexible?" in https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html

Comment: Sorry, @chinsoon12
I wanted to edit my 1st comment to "I see. We would have to.....". But editing is only allowed in 1st 5 mins. A classic case of importance of punctuation. Thank you for your help. Been through 2g too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about the application nor the computing efficiency of this solution, but it's concise to do:

```
x[y, on = .(a)][, .SD, .SDcols = names(y)]
```

Comment: Thank you @sindri_baldur
This would work too. However, how would I be able to fetch selected columns from x also e.g. x.b

Comment: Not sure I understand. It's hard without a concrete example... you could change to `.SDcols = names(x)` or simply: x[y, on = .(a)]... but I guess you are looking for neither of these?

Comment: Using your solution one would retrieve all columns from table `y`. Which does answer my original question. Thank you.

However, what if on top of the original question I'd also like to fetch a certain column from table `x` e.g. `x.b`
From the dummy data in question, column `b` resides in table `x`.

Comment: @T.Fung for this particular example you could do: `x[y, on = .(a)][, .SD, .SDcols = c(names(y), "b")]`